# Is it possible to draw a line into the future?

Tags: pine-script

For intraday timeframes.
Is it possible to draw a horizontal line on the first bar of the session, that has a length until the end of that session?
So, essentially drawing a line into the 'future'.

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible.
Code below is based on the answer of [PineCoders-LucF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11806240/pinecoders-lucf) to one of my previous questions [line.new draws 2 lines instead of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589661/line-new-draws-2-lines-instead-of-1)

```
//@version=4
study("FutureLine", overlay=true)

start = timestamp(2020,03,13,10,30,0)
stop = timestamp(2020,03,16,16,00,0)
level = 2575

var line ln = line.new(start, level, stop, level, xloc=xloc.bar_time)

if barstate.islast
    line.set_x1(ln, start)
    line.set_x2(ln, stop)
```

Which results in
[image]