# Plotting manual levels for daily high,low,close

Tags: pine-script

As I've already asked a couple of questions here in an attempt to solve my problem, this new question ties them all together and provides some context.
Previous questions related to this:

- [Is it possible to draw a line into the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659820/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-line-into-the-future)
- [Edit series only on certain dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060015/edit-series-only-on-certain-dates)
- [Set 2 series at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217589/set-2-series-at-once)
- [var does NOT keep it's value across bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61258554/var-does-not-keep-its-value-across-bars)
- [function returning 2 values to global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61302696/function-returning-2-values-to-global-variable)

I have a program (outside of TradingView) that tries to estimate the high/low/close levels of the ticker `SPX` for the next trading day.
I'm planning to plot this only on intraday timeframes (anything from 1 minute to 4 hours).
The only ticker I'm going to plot this on is `SPX`.

Now I'm trying to plot these levels in TradingView, to have a visual representation on how accurate the predicted levels are.
This means that I have a `high/low/close` value for every trading day.
The current dataset contains about 50 entries (so 50 days where I have a high/low/close level to plot) and will grow by 1 entry every trading day.
So in 1 year, the dataset will contain about 200 entries.

Because the dataset is larger than the number of drawing objects that can be displayed by TradingView, I've ruled out the use of drawing objects like `line.new()`.
The garbage collecter would cause only the last 50 or so drawn objects to be shown, and I'd like the full dataset to be displayed.
Therefore, I think I will need to resort to the `plot()` function.

This means I will end up with 3 series to plot: `high`, `low` and `close`.
Each will have a different value per trading date.
So essentially, I'm trying to manually create these 3 series by assigning them a value for each date.
But so far, I've failed to accomplish that.
I'm also trying to have only 1 data entry line per trading date to avoid clutter and to keep the code clean and maintainable.
Therefore, I'm trying to set these 3 data points per trading date with only 1 function.

The below script is my latest attempt with a reduced dataset of only 5 trading days for clarity.
I know the script below is wrong, because a variable cannot be re-used.
That's why it says `line 19: 'h' is already defined`.
I don't have a workaround for this, and I'd really like to find one.

```
//@version=4
study("Study", overlay=true)

// Variables    
var float dh = na
var float dl = na
var float dc = na

// Functions
isDate(y,m,d) => y==year and m==month and d==dayofmonth ? true:false 
d(y,m,d,h,l,c) => // Daily Levels
    if isDate(y,m,d)
        [h,l,c]
    else
        [na,na,na] 

// Set data for Daily High,Low,Close
[h,l,c] = d(2020,04,13,2800,2700,2725), dh:=h,dl:=l,dc:=c
[h,l,c] = d(2020,04,14,2850,2810,2825), dh:=h,dl:=l,dc:=c
[h,l,c] = d(2020,04,15,2800,2750,2710), dh:=h,dl:=l,dc:=c
[h,l,c] = d(2020,04,16,2850,2700,2790), dh:=h,dl:=l,dc:=c
[h,l,c] = d(2020,04,17,2900,2800,2850), dh:=h,dl:=l,dc:=c

// Plot Daily High,Low,Close
plot(dh, color=color.red)
plot(dl, color=color.green)
plot(dc, color=color.blue)
```

Another attempt is this code below, which does compile ok.

```
//@version=4
study("Functions test", overlay=true)

var float h = na
var float l = na
var float c = na

isDate(y,m,d) => y==year and m==month and d==dayofmonth ? true:false
setData() => 
    if isDate(2020,04,13)
        [2800,2700,2725]
    if isDate(2020,04,14)
        [2850,2810,2825]
    if isDate(2020,04,15)
        [2800,2750,2710]
    if isDate(2020,04,16)
        [2850,2700,2790]
    if isDate(2020,04,17)
        [2900,2800,2850]

[h1,l1,c1] = setData()

h := h1
l := l1
c := c1

plot(h,color=color.red)
plot(l,color=color.green)
plot(c,color=color.blue)
```

The problem here is that it only plots the values for the last date.

[image]

Comment: What's the context? What symbol/resolution does this have to run on? How many values like HLC are you looking to plot in all? How many individual initializations/dates are you going to be doing? For how many bars are you plotting custom level? Where are those levels coming from? It's your 3rd post on this subject. Would perhaps help us find optimal answers if you gave us more information.

Comment: I'm sorry if my original question was not clear. I've edited the question to provide as much information as possible, hoping this will provide a better perspective on my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should scale. Just POC it with lots of lines to be sure:

```
//@version=4
study("HLC Levels", "", true)

initOnDate(_y, _m, _d, _prev, _init) => 
    if _y == year and _m == month and _d == dayofmonth
        _init
    else
        _prev

float h = na
float l = na
float c = na
int   y = 0
int   m = 0
int   d = 0

y := 2020, m := 03, d := 31, h := initOnDate(y, m, d, h, 2600), l := initOnDate(y, m, d, l, 2500), c := initOnDate(y, m, d, c, 2525)
y := 2020, m := 04, d := 01, h := initOnDate(y, m, d, h, 2610), l := initOnDate(y, m, d, l, 2510), c := initOnDate(y, m, d, c, 2535)
y := 2020, m := 04, d := 02, h := initOnDate(y, m, d, h, 2620), l := initOnDate(y, m, d, l, 2520), c := initOnDate(y, m, d, c, 2545)

plot(h, "h", change(h) ? na : color.green,  1)
plot(l, "l", change(l) ? na : color.red,    1)
plot(c, "c", change(c) ? na : color.orange, 1)
```

[image]