# (non)persistance of VAR initializations in functions

Tags: pine-script

This is a follow-up to my previous question [Plotting custom data - daily = ok, weekly = not ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645323/plotting-custom-data-daily-ok-weekly-not-ok).
The comments on the accepted answer suggests that the state of a `var` inside a function is persisted throughout successive calls to that function.
This proved to be correct, because removing the `var` solved my problem.

However, I now have a test case that seems to prove the opposite.
In the script below, variable `b` seems NOT to be persisted.

Function `f2()` has to be called on every bar in order to evaluate the `if` statement.
That is the case, since the plot of `y` is equal to the number of bars.

Because function `f2()` also calls `f1()`, I expect variable `b` inside of `f1()` to also increase by 1 on each bar.
The final value of `b` inside of `f1()` is retrieved on the last bar, and stored in `z`.

To my surprise, the value of `z` after the last bar showed to be 1.
This means that either:

- `var` variables are not persisted within a function (disproved by my
  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645323/plotting-custom-data-daily-ok-weekly-not-ok))
- nested function calls have their own execution context.

Can't think of another reason for this behaviour.
Can someone confirm this, or maybe provide an alternate explanation?

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround")

var int y = 0
var int z = 0

f1() =>
    var int b = 0
    b := b + 1
    b

f2() =>
    f1()
    true

if true and f2()
    y := y + 1

if barstate.islast
    z := f1()

plot(y, title="y")
plot(z, title="z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Different instances of a call to the same function each maintain their own context, as you surmised. So in your case, the call to `f1()` from within `f2()` maintains a different context than the one made from within the `if barstate.islast` block.

This has both advantages and disadvantages. It entails a persistent variable (i.e., initialized with `var`) local to a function's scope cannot be shared by calling the same function from 2 different places in the script, but it allows repeated use of a function in a context like the 3 consecutive `f_print()` calls.

We are discussing persistent vars here, but the concept extends to the series values created by function calls, and so the values retrieved when using the history-referencing operator on local variables.