# Boolean expression evaluation and performance

Tags: pine-script

I think there's a flaw in the way that Pine Script evaluates boolean expressions, that can hugely affect performance.

See this example

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", overlay=true)

var int y = 0

f1() =>
    label.new(bar_index, high)
    true

if false and f1()
    y := y + 1

plot(y, title="y")
```

The statement `if false and f1()` should not need to evaluate the outcome of function `f1()` in order to know that the result will always be `false`.
However - as demonstrated by the fact that labels are drawn on the chart - the function `f1()` is still executed on every bar.
So Pine Script seems to evaluate the **entire** expression before making a decision, which is unnecessary.

Don't know if this is by design, but I think this should be corrected.

***Contextual info***
I have a script that contains a huge number of consecutive if statements to check wether the current bar is on a certain date.
In an attempt to improve the performance, I added a boolean variable to be evaluated first on each `if` statement.
(an example can be seen in the `f_prediction_daily()` function in [Plotting custom data - daily = ok, weekly = not ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645323/plotting-custom-data-daily-ok-weekly-not-ok))
But as my list of `if` statements grew larger I noticed a decrease in performance.
Therefore, I've created this little test and question.

Comment: Pinescript is an awful abomination of JavaScript.

Comment: I am fiddling for an hour around, why my script tries to access an "na" value and the problem of the topic was my only explanation, but I couldn't believe it. And yeah, it's unbelievable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The evaluation of boolean expressions does not currently short-circuit in Pine, so all elements in the expression are evaluated.