# Horizontal line on chart on TradingView

Tags: pivot, pine-script, horizontal-line

I'm using charts on TradingView and I'd like to draw horizontal lines.
The horizontal lines are the Pivot Points.

I've calculated them and each values is stocked in a variable.

```
width = input(2, minval=1)
xHigh  = security(tickerid,"D", high[1])
xLow   = security(tickerid,"D", low[1])
xClose = security(tickerid,"D", close[1])
vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3
vR1 = vPP+(vPP-xLow)
vS1 = vPP-(xHigh - vPP)
vR2 = vPP + (xHigh - xLow)
vS2 = vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 = xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow) 
vS3 = xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)
```

I've tried to use this line to do the job

```
plot(vPP, color=black, title="vPP", style = line, linewidth = width)
```

But from one day to another, the line doesn't cut. So it's not looking good. See the picture.
[image]

This is the result I am looking for :

[image]

I'd like :

- to display today and yesterday pivot points.
- that the lines starts from today until the end of the session
- to write "PP, S1/S2/S3, R1/R2/R3" in front of the lines

Thanks for your advises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the connecting line, you have to use color `na` when the value changes.
For a code example, see the answer of [PineCoders-LucF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11806240/pinecoders-lucf) to one of my questions [Plotting manual levels for daily high,low,close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308738/plotting-manual-levels-for-daily-high-low-close)

Edit: Your code example, modified to work as you intended.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

width = input(2, minval=1)
xHigh  = security(syminfo.ticker,"D", high[1])
xLow   = security(syminfo.ticker,"D", low[1])
xClose = security(syminfo.ticker,"D", close[1])

vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3
vR1 = vPP+(vPP-xLow)
vS1 = vPP-(xHigh - vPP)
vR2 = vPP + (xHigh - xLow)
vS2 = vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 = xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow) 
vS3 = xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)

plot(vPP, color=change(vPP) ? na : color.black, title="vPP", style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = width)
```

As requested in the comments, code for @version=3.
Remark: You should really use @version=4 to access the latest Pine script capabilities.

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true)

width = input(2, minval=1)
xHigh  = security(tickerid,"D", high[1])
xLow   = security(tickerid,"D", low[1])
xClose = security(tickerid,"D", close[1])

vPP = (xHigh+xLow+xClose) / 3
vR1 = vPP+(vPP-xLow)
vS1 = vPP-(xHigh - vPP)
vR2 = vPP + (xHigh - xLow)
vS2 = vPP - (xHigh - xLow)
vR3 = xHigh + 2 * (vPP - xLow) 
vS3 = xLow - 2 * (xHigh - vPP)

plot(vPP, color=change(vPP) ? na : black, title="vPP", style = linebr, linewidth = width)
```

Comment: So i've added this code line : "float vPP = na" at the beginning and then "plot(vPP, change(vPP) ? na : color.black, title="vPP", style = linebr, linewidth = width)". However it get this error : "Script could not be translated from: |B|float vPP = na|E|
|B|." Any idea ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your code example.

Answer (score 0):

try `style = plot.style_linebr` instead of `style = line`
or

```
style = linebr
```

Comment: "Error: Undeclared identifier `plot.style_linebr` "
with the line "plot(vPP, color=black, title="vPP", style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth = width)"

Comment: what version are you using? maybe just style = linebr

Comment: first solution gives this error : Error: Undeclared identifier `style_linebr`
second solution gives no error, however the result is the same as the 1st picture
I dont know about the version.. i'd say v3, because i've tried the function "line.new()" and it didn't work because it was not recognized

Comment: I guess linebr doesn"t solve the problem because there is no missing data ...